# Trigger file upload from within AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive for uploads. I would like to have a link/button that will trigger the file dialog and am having issues getting it to open.

My directive template is a bit like this:

```
<div>
 <div class="dropzone"></div>
 <input type="file" multiple onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFiles(this)">
 <a class="upload">Add new image</a>
</div>
```

In my link function (at this point I am not even bothering with the A tag - just trying to get it to open on load) I am trigger a click. Note that I do not have jQuery.

I have tried things such as:

```
$timeout(function() {
    elem.find('input').triggerHandler('click');
}, 0);
```

And

```
elem[1].click();
```

As well as:

```
elem[1].triggerHandler('click');
```

But all give me errors such as:

```
 undefined is not an object (evaluating 'elem[1].triggerHandler')
```

Or no errors but no activity.

Basically I would like the A tag, on click, to open the file dialog. At this point I am fine using find() with element names since they are unique for now.

Comment: As a sanity check, you could try assigning your file input an ID and trying `document.getElementById(...).click()` to see if that is able to trigger the file dialog (should be OK on modern browsers).

Comment: Thanks that put me on right track. Turns out you can't do what I did. The click event must be user initiated (such as clicking on a link).